# Not getting body response of Curl

Tags: php, curl

Hello,

```
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      // try to get an access token
      $code = $_GET['code'];
      $url = '<token endpoint here>'; // Token endpoint
      $params = array(
         "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
         "code" => $code,
         "redirect_uri" => '<redirect uri here>',
         "scope" => "openid",
     );
       $client_id = '<client id here>';
       $client_secret = '<client secret here>';
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array("Authorization: Basic".$client_id.":".$client_secret, 'Accept:application/json'));
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
       $output = curl_exec($ch);
       $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
       $header = substr($output, 0, $header_size);
       $body = substr($output, $header_size);
       curl_close($ch);
       print_r($header);print_r('this is'. $body);
       die;
    }
```

I'm getting the header response with some status `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` along wth some other parameters like Content type etc. But I'm not getting the access token from this end. Can anyone assist me with a solution.

Comment: start by doing a `print_r($output);`

Comment: It is giving the same header status content type etc

Comment: can you show the output?

Comment: when debugging, use var_dump, not echo or print_r